# Why can Sonic become a Super Saiyan like Goku?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, sonic-the-hedgehog-series

I watched an animation about Sonic, and that hedgehog became a Super Saiyan using diamond shaped stuff.

What actually is that? How can Sonic become like that?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're refering to what's commonly known as [Super Sonic](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Sonic).

[image: Super Sonic from Sonic X]

Sonic has had the ability to turn into Super Sonic using [Chaos Emerald](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Chaos_Emerald) since the 2nd game. Various media have handeled this transformation in various ways (see the Wikia-page linked above), but in general he's seen as a yellow or golden version of himself. He usually gain enhanced speed and an ability to fly and/or to survive in outer space. At least in the games, this is often at expense of [Rings](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Ring).

The transformation is *not directly linked* to Super Saiyans, but it's widely believed that the game drew heavy inspiration from Dragon Ball in this regard. (No official confirmation, tough.)

Comment: And of course the idea that Super Sonic is a Super Saiyan is a popular fanon (i.e. something that some fans believe but which is not backed up by any actual canon).